# Changing Zend\Dom\Document for \XMLReader

Tags: php, domdocument, xmlreader

I need to change from using: Zend\Dom\Document and Zend\Dom\Document\Query to using XMLReader, as parsing the DOM Document way ends up using too much memory.

This is the line I need to replace with XMLReader() [looping per line?]:

```
$pages = Query::execute('//page[@id=45894]|//node[@id=45894]|//node[@id=45894]/node|//node[@id=45894]/node/node', $domDocument);
```

What I'm unsure about is doing the same XPath query with one loop ?

**EDIT:**
I came across hakre's [xmlreader-iterators](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator) and have now tried:

```
if (get_class($reader) === Document::class) {
    /** @var Document $reader */
    $nodes = Query::execute($queryXpath, $reader);
} elseif (get_class($reader) === XMLReaderInterface::class) {
    /** @var XMLReaderInterface $reader */
    $nodes = null;

    $xmlElementIterator = new \XMLElementIterator($reader);
    $nodes = new \XMLElementXpathFilter($xmlElementIterator, $queryXpath);

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->createElement('root');
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        /* @var $node \XMLReaderNode */
        $element = $node->getSimpleXMLElement();
        $domElement = dom_import_simplexml($element);
        $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($domElement));
    }

    $nodes = $doc->childNodes;

    $reader->reset();
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Invalid reader type, must use for example: Document or XMLReader.');
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use: [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) ?

Comment: I would still need to use XMLReader prior to open the file and parse line by line as DOM Document uses too much memory, unsure how you'd use with SimpleXMLElement ?

Comment: There is a built in function [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to load file and create SimpleXMLElement which is readable and iterable object